# Mysql reorder menu

Tags: php, mysql

if I have three menus

```
id | name | order
--------------------
1  | Foo  | 1
2  | Bar  | 2
3  | Blah | 3
```

and click the link `menu/up/1`, I need to set order of menu with id `1` to `2` and menu with id `2` to `1`.

I have tried (PDO)

```
public static function goDown($id) {
    if(!$id) {
        return false;
    }

    self::connect();
    self::prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM menu');
    $count = self::fetch();

    if(isset($count['count(*)'])) {
        self::prepare('UPDATE menu SET order = order - 1 WHERE order = :count');
        self::bindValue('count', $count['count(*)']);
        self::execute();

        self::prepare('UPDATE menu SET order = order + 1 WHERE id = :id AND order < :count');
        self::bindValue('id', $id);
        self::bindValue('count', $count['count(*)']);

        return self::execute();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT - MY SOLUTION:**

```
public static function goDown($id) {
    if(!$id) {
        return false;
    }

    self::connect();
    self::prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM menu');
    $count = self::fetch();

    if(isset($count['count(*)'])) {
        self::prepare('SELECT ordem FROM menu WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
        self::bindValue('id', $id);
        $ordem = self::fetch();

        self::prepare('UPDATE menu SET ordem = ordem - 1 WHERE ordem = :ordem');
        self::bindValue('ordem', $ordem['ordem'] + 1);
        self::execute();

        self::prepare('UPDATE menu SET ordem = ordem + 1 WHERE id = :id AND ordem < :count');
        self::bindValue('id', $id);
        self::bindValue('count', $count['count(*)']);

        return self::execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your table definition and keys are set up, but you will probably have to have an overlapping number for a split second. If that is ok, then do something like this:

The safest:

```
SELECT order FROM menu WHERE id = :id; /* One to go up; */
SELECT id, order FROM menu WHERE order = :existingOrder + 1; /* One to go down */

UPDATE menu SET order = order + 1 WHERE id = :id; /* Putting it up */
UPDATE menu SET order = :existingOrder WHERE id = :existingId
```

This uses an extra query, but is much safer. You can also validate that it isn't at the top/bottom, too as that will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a72d) out.

It'll be quite easy for you to transalte it to PDO:

```
set @id := 10;
select @count := count(*) from t;
select @prevOrder := least(anorder + 1, @count) from t where id = @id;
select @prevId := id from t where anorder = @prevOrder;

update t set anorder = anorder - 1 where id = @prevId;    
update t set anorder = anorder + 1 where id = @id;
```

Basically it decreases the order of the selected ID (`@id`) without falling down (that's the `least` function) and increases the one that was previously in that place.

Comment: Thanks, but I need 6 query to this, or not?